# .slideToggle(); works on every other div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr, slidetoggle

I'm trying to work with `slideToggle` in order to show post information when clicking on a `+` sign.

You can see the progress on a test blog here: http://noitsnotitsnotokay.tumblr.com/

So far, this is what I have for the HTML and for the Javascript (the HTML portion repeats for every post, and because of Tumblr defauts, I can't create a new class for every post):

```
<div id="info">
<div class="pstinfo">
    <!-- info here -->
</div>
<span class="plsign">+</span>
</div>

<script>
$("div.pstinfo").hide();
$("span.plsign").click(function() {
$(this).parent().children("div.pstinfo").stop().slideToggle("slow");
return false;
});
</script>
```

As you can probably see in the test blog, it works in one post, and in the next, it won't open all the way. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I've had some mixed results using `parent()` without a selector - I'd strongly suggest using `.closest('.info')` instead of `.parent()` - also, the `.stop()` may be causing issues.  Have you tried it without the .stop? Or added some of the optional parameters to `.stop(true, true)` ?

Comment: .closest doesn't seem to be working at all...the parameters did help, but now the divs that wouldn't open are simply appearing and closing. Progress, though!

Comment: Well, it may be due to the fact that the `<script>` is included multiple times in the page. So, one instance will try to show the `<div>` while the next immediately hides it, and repeat for each subsequent inclusion. You'll want to adjust the page so the `<script>` is only included once independent of the posts.

Comment: That does make more sense...adding an external sheet doesn't seem to help, either. It's just strange that it doesn't work for every div! Oh, well, thank you so much anyway!

Comment: Before try to find and solve your problem, there's another thing you need to check out and fixit... you can't repeat the code each time a block of content is inserted. First, you MUST have `unique ID's` in the page.. the `jQuery` bind actions only need to be set it up ONCE, if you need more, try with `functions`... And that's all in the first quick view.  Fix that first, and only then debug your code and fix the errors if any. Oh.. and the example page, must be a fiddle or simmilar.. your page is changing and It's not going to be in that stage for ever.

Comment: That's something Tumblr automatically introduces. It uses {Block:Posts} {/Block:Posts}, and anything outside blocks for individual posts will be repeated throughout. I can't prevent the repetition unless I repeat the code in each individual post type's block, which I've tried, as well.

Comment: Oooh, I see your point - placing the script outside {/Block:Posts}, with the divs inside. Wow, that actually did the trick, thank you!

Comment: Then you have to use  class instead of ID's... And the script should not be there

Comment: I'll put it as an answer then, so that this thread can be considered solved.
I'm glad you solved.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem I see in your code, is that you are repeating the code block each time on each comment.

So, you have multiple `DIV` with same `ID` & Multiple `<script>` blocks with the same bind actions.

like:

```
{Block:Posts}
    <div><!-- // code in OP example (html+ID+Class+js) --></div>
{/Block:Posts}
```

That give you:

```
<div><!-- // code in OP example (html+ID+Class+js) --></div>
<div><!-- // code in OP example (html+ID+Class+js) --></div>
<div><!-- // code in OP example (html+ID+Class+js) --></div>
...
```

#### Error example with the OP code: http://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/2fUjr/

---

I' will suggest to do before anything else, to change that to something like:

```
{Block:Posts}
    <div><!-- // HTML code in OP example (only class, no ID) --></div>
{/Block:Posts}
<script> /* JS in OP example (outside the loop) */ </script>
```

That will give us something like:

```
<div><!-- // HTML code in OP example (only class) --></div>
<div><!-- // HTML code in OP example (only class) --></div>
<div><!-- // HTML code in OP example (only class) --></div>
<script>  /* JS in OP example (only once) */ </script>
```

#### Working example with the suggested format: http://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/2fUjr/1/

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Unc2U/5/

EDIT: Since your JS didn't seem to like .next(), lets try .siblings().

```
$(".pstinfo").hide();
$(".plsign").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".pstinfo").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: That was my initial code - without .stop(), the box opens and closes various times (I believe the amount of times it opens and closes corresponds to the amount of divs on the page). And without the $(this) section, it opens and closes all of the divs on the page at once, while I'd like them to open individually.

Comment: Doesn't open...also, the problem with the .stop() persists :S

Comment: What if you try making it `$(".plsign").click(function(e) {` and then adding `e.preventDefault()` above the `$(this)`?

Comment: Seems to be reacting the same way...I don't believe JavaScript is too fond of me :P

Comment: I tried using `.siblings()` and it seems to work on JSFiddle as well. Any luck on your end?